# How to select multiple fields from multiple tables without relationship between them?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 4 different tables, with field Id. I want to create a fifth table with four fields; each field a list of all the id's from each table respectively. The id's have nothing to do with each other, so I can't think of what to join them on. If I do a union I won't know which table record came from. Is there any way I can do this?

[image]

Comment: This is very hard to do in MS Access.

Comment: If the id's have nothing to do with each other, what is the use of putting them together in one table? What is it that you want to achieve? If we understand that, maybe we can help you.

Comment: It would be easy with a VBA recordset loop. But do all 4 tables have the same number of rows?

Comment: @Andre, No. they don't.

Comment: @massie, I need this product for QA purposes. I think I explained very well **what** I need.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Very hard, or impossible? I don't mind using a very complicated sub/join query.

Comment: But then your resulting table would be filled pretty random, no? Just 4 columns of unrelated data?

Comment: @Andre, Yes. Think of it as four different lists next to each other. I realize it doesn't make much sense, But it is what I need for my later queries.

Comment: If your result could be not database table, but excel worksheet, then it would be quite easy :) Otherwise it is hard - you should start with queries, able to simulate row_number() function; then you should join these by simulated row_number etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in VBA, using DAO methods. For brevity I have included only table1 and table3. Untested, but it should work. :)

```vb
Public Sub FillResult()

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim rsT As DAO.Recordset    ' Target
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset, rs3 As DAO.Recordset  ' Source tables

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    ' Clean out result table
    DB.Execute "DELETE * FROM tResult"
    Set rsT = DB.OpenRecordset("tResult", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    Set rs1 = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Id FROM table1", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rs3 = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT aId FROM table3", dbOpenSnapshot)

    ' Main loop runs as long as there are records left in at least one source table
    Do While Not (rs1.EOF And rs3.EOF)
        ' Add new record in tResult
        rsT.AddNew

        ' For each source table: if not EOF, copy current value to target table and move to next record
        If Not rs1.EOF Then
            rsT!table1 = rs1!ID
            rs1.MoveNext
        End If

        If Not rs3.EOF Then
            rsT!table3 = rs3!aID
            rs3.MoveNext
        End If

        rsT.Update
    Loop
    rsT.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can combine all this tables using full outer join (for MS Access diff logic using UNION) and exclude/handle the NULL values on further queries.

for  `MS Access`

```
SELECT t1.[id] table1,NULL table2,NULL table3,NULL table4 FROM table1 t1 UNION
SELECT NULL table1,t2.[id] table2,NULL table3,NULL table4 FROM table2 t2 UNION
SELECT NULL table1,NULL table2,t3.[aid] table3,NULL table4 FROM table3 t3 UNION
SELECT NULL table1,NULL table2,NULL table3,t4.[bid] table4 FROM table4 t4
```

Result :

```
table1  table2  table3  table4
11      NULL    NULL    NULL
32      NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    22      NULL    NULL
NULL    45      NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    1       NULL
NULL    NULL    5       NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    2
NULL    NULL    NULL    7
```

I know this is not the exact solution, but may be helpful.

For SQL Server you can do this way

```
SELECT t1.[id]  table1
    ,t2.[id]    table2
    ,t3.[aid]   table3
    ,t4.[bid]   table4
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
FULL OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.aid
FULL OUTER JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.id = t4.bid
```

But this also will produce the NULL values and need to exclude/handle this NULL values on further queries.

Comment: Does MS Access support full outer join? IIRC no.

Comment: we can use some other logic (UNION) to implement full outer join in  MS Access. Result modified. But this also will produce the NULL values and need to exclude/handle this NULL values on further queries. I know this is not the exact solution, but may be helpful.